# How to make loading screen in ReactJS web app like splash in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a **ReactJS** web app that it has to initiate some data at the starting load time (after entering Url in the browser). For example, my web app calls API for checking whether the token is valid, loading profile information ... I want to show loading page at that time until the initial process finishes.

How to do that?

I use **react router v4** in my project.

The initial process happens only one time until the user closes tab of my app in the browser.

My web app have multiple routes. It means that my app have many pages. The initial must always run after user enter whatever route in browser Url. For example my app have routes like that:

```
<route path="/about" component={about}>
<route path="/admin" component={admin}>
<route path="/dashboard" component={dashboard}>
```

When the user enters http://localhost:3000/about or http://localhost:3000/admin or [localhost:3000/dashboard](http://localhost:3000/dashboard) in the browser, then my App must init data and shows loading page, when init finish my app render the corresponding page.

**Update**
To clear question:

The solution of my question can be:

- having a variable mark initiate is running or initiate has finished
- in every pages, i check mentioned above variable and render loading or content of page corresponding.

But this solution have problem that where put the code doing data initiate? 
you know that user can enter whatever page url to access my web app so that i have to add the code doing init to every pages of my web app. This not good way because code repeats.

So i want to have one component that doing data initial and render loading until it finish. After initiate finishes, it render corresponding page depends on url. How to implement that using React router v4?

Comment: do you mean any async function should run before routing?

Comment: @EmadEmami sounds like he wants an opaque loader

Comment: yep, i want to show somethings like opaque loader. I think i can do this by the follow approach:
- adding a variable finishInit = false in redux store, 
- when initiate finishes i will update finishInit = true. 
- every pages i must render loading if (finishInit = false) otherwise i will render the content of page.
The problem is that every pages must implement that code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional rendering.

Initiate data loading in `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` and `setState` when data loading is completed. Then apply conditional rendering in the render method based on the status of the state.

You can take help from this snippet:

```
constructor(props){
  this.state = {status: null}
}

componentWillMount(){
  function_initiateDataLoading((data)=>{
    this.setState({status: data})
  })
}

render(){
  return this.tate.status == null ? <LoadingComponent/> : <FinalComponent/>
}
```

Comment: I know this way, but my problem is that every pages need common data fetched from Api X so if i implement initiate like your above snippet then i have to implement call Api X in all pages because the user can enter whatever page url. So  I want to have only one component that make init data instead of every page init common data.
So how to do that?